# Trying to keep dropdown menus flush to the edge of header regardless of change in viewport size

Tags: html, css, bulma

I have a somewhat mobile responsive header, but there are some dropdown menus that I would like to keep flush to the edge of the header element regardless of changes in viewport size as the header adjusts.

I tried putting those dropdowns in their own element such as a div or section and adding all the same css from the individual selectors, but I did not make progress there.

```js
// The Dropdown for New-units
const newUnitDropdown = document.querySelector(".new_units");
newUnitDropdown.innerHTML = `
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-trigger">
    <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu">
    <i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
    <span>New Units</span>
      <span class="icon is-small">
        <!--fontawesome required for the icon-->
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
`;

// The Dropdown for Overlay
const overlayDropdown = document.querySelector(".overlay");
overlayDropdown.innerHTML = `
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-trigger">
    <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu">
      <span>Select Overlay</span>
      <span class="icon is-small">
        <!--fontawesome required for the icon-->
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
`;

// The Dropdown for Cities
const cityDropdown = document.querySelector(".cities");
cityDropdown.innerHTML = `
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-trigger">
    <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu">
      <span>Choose a city</span>
      <span class="icon is-small">
        <!--fontawesome required for the icon-->
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href='#' data-value="oak" class='oak dropdown-item'>
        Oakland, CA
      </a>
      <a href='#' data-value="san" class='san dropdown-item'>
        San Francisco, CA
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
`;

const dropdown = document.querySelector(".dropdown");

document.querySelector(".dropdown-trigger").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  dropdown.classList.toggle("is-active");
});

document.addEventListener(
  "click",
  (event) => {
    // event.preventDefault();
    if (event !== null && event.target instanceof HTMLElement) {
      const element = event.target;
      if (element.matches(".dropdown-item.oak")) {
        console.log("Oakland was clicked");

        customMap.addOakland();
        data.forEach((label) => customMap.addCircleMarker(label));
        console.log("inside the if conditional", data);
        dropdown.classList.toggle("active");
      }
      if (element.matches(".dropdown-item.san")) {
        console.log("San Francisco was clicked");
        customMap.addSanFran();
        data.forEach((label) => customMap.addCircleMarker(label));
        dropdown.classList.toggle("active");
      }
    }
  },
  false
);

// Checkbox Menu
const checkboxMenu = document.querySelector(".checkbox");
checkboxMenu.innerHTML = `
<nav class="panel">
  <div class="panel-block">
    <p class="control has-icons-left">
      <input class="input" type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search">
      <span class="icon is-left">
        <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <ul id="myUL">
    <li><a class="panel-block is-active">
    <input type="checkbox" id="density" name="density" value="density">
      Density
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" style="color:#b19cd9"></i></span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="panel-block">
    <input type="checkbox" id="holc" name="" value="holc">
      HOLC
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" style="color:#b19cd9"></i></span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="panel-block">
    <input type="checkbox" id="tcac" name="" value="tcac">
      TCAC
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" style="color:#b19cd9"></i></span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="panel-block">
    <input type="checkbox" id="population" name="" value="population">
      Population
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" style="color:#b19cd9"></i></span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="panel-block">
    <input type="checkbox" id="zoning" name="" value="zoning">
      Zoning
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" style="color:#b19cd9"></i></span>
    </a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
`;

const fetchLabel = () => {
  let input, filter, ul, li, a, i, textValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    textValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (textValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};

const input = document.querySelector("input");
input.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
  fetchLabel();
});
```

```css
.checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
}

.cales {
  width: 250px;
}

.cities {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 95px;
  left: 350px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.fas.fa-circle {
  color: #fe0302;
  padding: 2px;
}

.hero {
  background-color: #e5e7e9;
}

.hero-body {
  padding: 12px;
}

/* style the map box */
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto !important;
  position: relative;
  /* z-index: -2; */
}

.navbar-item {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.new_units {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 95px;
  /* left: 100px; */
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 95px;
  left: 180px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.panel {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.title {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.title:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css"
    />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/custom.css">
  <title>CALES Maps POC</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="hero">
    <div class="hero-body">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="title">
          CALES
        </h1>
        <span class="cales">Comprehensive Assessment of Land Use Entitlements</span>
            <div class="navbar-brand">
              <span class="navbar-burger" data-target="navbarMenuHeroA">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div id="navbarMenuHeroA" class="navbar-menu">
              <div class="navbar-end">
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  Map & Data
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  Rankings
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  Topics
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  Cities
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  About
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  Updates
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </section>

  <div id="map" style="height: 100vh;"></div>

    <div class="new_units"></div>

    <div class="overlay"></div>

    <div class="checkbox"></div>

    <div class="cities"></div>
  

  <script type="text/javascript" src="./src/index.ts"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

S Fiddle does not do it justice though. I would copy it over to a code editor and use a browser. I have had a friend tweak it in JS Fiddle where using `display: inline-block` fixes it...in JS Fiddle, not in the browser.

This is what it looks like in iPad Pro:

[image]

So again I am trying to get that dropdown to be flush to the gray navbar regardless of iPad Pro view or thereabouts. I am only worried about the iPad Pro view mostly for now.

Would love for that logo not to break like that when resized. This is all from Bulma CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little bit of CSS tweaking and consolidating. I removed the individual styles set for each of those four floating elements and added them to one `.fixed_under_header` class element.

This CSS should do the trick:

```css
.hero-body {
  position: relative;
}

.fixed_under_header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.fixed_under_header > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: fit-content;
}

.fixed_under_header > div + div {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Here is the full working solution:

```js
// The Dropdown for New-units
const newUnitDropdown = document.querySelector(".new_units");
newUnitDropdown.innerHTML = `
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-trigger">
    <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu">
    <i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
    <span>New Units</span>
      <span class="icon is-small">
        <!--fontawesome required for the icon-->
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
`;

// The Dropdown for Overlay
const overlayDropdown = document.querySelector(".overlay");
overlayDropdown.innerHTML = `
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-trigger">
    <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu">
      <span>Select Overlay</span>
      <span class="icon is-small">
        <!--fontawesome required for the icon-->
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
`;

// The Dropdown for Cities
const cityDropdown = document.querySelector(".cities");
cityDropdown.innerHTML = `
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-trigger">
    <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu">
      <span>Choose a city</span>
      <span class="icon is-small">
        <!--fontawesome required for the icon-->
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href='#' data-value="oak" class='oak dropdown-item'>
        Oakland, CA
      </a>
      <a href='#' data-value="san" class='san dropdown-item'>
        San Francisco, CA
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
`;

const dropdown = document.querySelector(".dropdown");

document.querySelector(".dropdown-trigger").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  dropdown.classList.toggle("is-active");
});

document.addEventListener(
  "click",
  (event) => {
    // event.preventDefault();
    if (event !== null && event.target instanceof HTMLElement) {
      const element = event.target;
      if (element.matches(".dropdown-item.oak")) {
        console.log("Oakland was clicked");

        customMap.addOakland();
        data.forEach((label) => customMap.addCircleMarker(label));
        console.log("inside the if conditional", data);
        dropdown.classList.toggle("active");
      }
      if (element.matches(".dropdown-item.san")) {
        console.log("San Francisco was clicked");
        customMap.addSanFran();
        data.forEach((label) => customMap.addCircleMarker(label));
        dropdown.classList.toggle("active");
      }
    }
  },
  false
);

// Checkbox Menu
const checkboxMenu = document.querySelector(".checkbox");
checkboxMenu.innerHTML = `
<nav class="panel">
  <div class="panel-block">
    <p class="control has-icons-left">
      <input class="input" type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search">
      <span class="icon is-left">
        <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <ul id="myUL">
    <li><a class="panel-block is-active">
    <input type="checkbox" id="density" name="density" value="density">
      Density
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" style="color:#b19cd9"></i></span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="panel-block">
    <input type="checkbox" id="holc" name="" value="holc">
      HOLC
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" style="color:#b19cd9"></i></span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="panel-block">
    <input type="checkbox" id="tcac" name="" value="tcac">
      TCAC
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" style="color:#b19cd9"></i></span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="panel-block">
    <input type="checkbox" id="population" name="" value="population">
      Population
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" style="color:#b19cd9"></i></span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="panel-block">
    <input type="checkbox" id="zoning" name="" value="zoning">
      Zoning
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" style="color:#b19cd9"></i></span>
    </a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
`;

const fetchLabel = () => {
  let input, filter, ul, li, a, i, textValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    textValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (textValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};

const input = document.querySelector("input");
input.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
  fetchLabel();
});
```

```css
.hero-body {
  position: relative;
}

.fixed_under_header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.fixed_under_header > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: fit-content;
}

.fixed_under_header > div + div {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.cales {
  width: 250px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.fas.fa-circle {
  color: #fe0302;
  padding: 2px;
}

.hero {
  background-color: #e5e7e9;
}

.hero-body {
  padding: 12px;
}

/* style the map box */
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto !important;
  position: relative;
  /* z-index: -2; */
}

.navbar-item {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.panel {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.title {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.title:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css"
    />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/custom.css">
  <title>CALES Maps POC</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="hero">
    <header class="hero-body">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="title">
          CALES
        </h1>
        <span class="cales">Comprehensive Assessment of Land Use Entitlements</span>
            <div class="navbar-brand">
              <span class="navbar-burger" data-target="navbarMenuHeroA">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div id="navbarMenuHeroA" class="navbar-menu">
              <div class="navbar-end">
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  Map & Data
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  Rankings
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  Topics
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  Cities
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  About
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  Updates
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="fixed_under_header">
          <div class="new_units"></div>
          <div class="overlay"></div>
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <div class="cities"></div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </section>

  <div id="map" style="height: 100vh;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./src/index.ts"></script>
</body>
</html>
```